# order not following in spring integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

My requirement is need to upload the file and then need to move the file to processing.Some times I am seeing error saying that the file is moved or deleted. This may be because  the file is moved to process before file transfer is completely done.

configurations are

```
<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="publishToSFTPChannel" ></int:publish-subscribe-channel>


<file:inbound-channel-adapter
directory="file:#{configurationService.configuration.getProperty('csv.export.file.location')}"
id="fileInbound" channel="publishToSFTPChannel" filename-pattern="*.csv" >
<int:poller fixed-rate="11000"  max-messages-per-poll="100"/>
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>


<int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter id="sftpOutboundAdapter"
session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
channel="publishToSFTPChannel"
charset="UTF-8"
remote-directory="#{csvRemoteDirectory}" 
remote-file-separator="/" order="1" />


<file:outbound-channel-adapter id="moveProcessedFile"
    channel="publishToSFTPChannel"
    directory="file:#{configurationService.configuration.getProperty('auspost.csv.export.file.location')}/${tenantId}/processed"
```

Can you provide some inputs how can hold order 2 until order 1 is completed